# How can I block Firefox from allowing me to create new profiles?

Tags: firefox, productivity

I'm very easily distracted so I use [Leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) with Firefox to help me focus while I'm at work.  This works great (especially because I have it set to require a 64-character password in order to make any changes to the settings).  I have one profile for "personal" stuff where only a few sites (e.g. Pandora) are always allowed and everything else is only unblocked for a few minutes each hour (I give myself those few minutes each hour to take a break, check facebook or personal email, etc.).  In the "work" profile, all distracting sites are blocked.  I'm pretty good about actively blocking new sites that I get to that are not work-related.

Unfortunately I've now grown accustomed to just creating a new Firefox profile whenever I want to go to a page that's blocked in both profiles.  It's too easy to start with the profile manager, and when Firefox starts with the new profile, of course there are no extensions so every site is available.

Is there any way to remove the ability to add a new profile or start the profile manager (or at least make it reasonably difficult to do so)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just desensitizing yourself to the amount of work required to bypass your own restrictions. If you make it difficult or impossible to create a new profile, you would also know how to undo that change. Or you would open a different browser, or go to the page with a proxy, etc.

Firefox profiles are not something used by the majority of people, so I would be inclined to say you are fairly technical. You will be able to figure out how to bypass your own restrictions, and adding another layer will help in the short run but do nothing in the long run.

However, you wanted an actual answer, so here is one. Create two shortcuts on your desktop and modify the executable string so that it loads one of the two profiles automatically.

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "Work Profile"`

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "Personal Profile"`

From here on, if you needed to create a new profile, you would need to create a new shortcut and specifically change the argument to start the profile manager. The profile manager will not start automatically, thus adding yet another layer to (hopefully) dissuade you from going to the unproductive site.